# Comparing values in an array

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, parameters

I am creating a dice game which will use an array of integers to store values rolled on the die and has methods that allow the user to roll the die, find out the total of all values rolled on the die etc.

The method rollAndStore() rolls the die once and stores that value in the array.

In my method called howMany(), the parameter: "value" will be an integer between 1 and 6 inclusive. The method is meant to count how many times that value was rolled on the die from the values currently stored in the array rolledValues[]. For instance, if the user entered a value of 4, the method should count how many times the number 4 was rolled on the die and then compare it with the value stored in the array. I need to return the calculated value.

So far I have wrote:

```
private int[] rolledValues;
private Die die;

public DiceGame(int arraySize)
{
    rolledValues = new int[arraySize];
    die = new Die();

}

public void rollAndStore(int roll1){

    if (roll1 > rolledValues.length){
        //Do Nothing
        ;

    } else if (roll1 >= 0 && roll1 < rolledValues.length){

        die.roll();
        rolledValues[roll1] = die.roll();

    }

}

public int howMany(int value){



    if (value >= 1 && value <= 6){

       for (int i = 0; i < rolledValues.length; i++){

        }

    }

    return ;

}
```

I'm not sure what to write inside the for loop to make this work.

Comment: declare and instantiate an `int total` before the loop. Increment that sum in the loop if `rolledValues[i] == value`. `return sum;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int howMany(int value){
  // i prefer checks at the beginnin with a return
  if(value < 0) return -1; 
  if(value > 6) return -1; 

  int total = 0;
  // loop over all rolled values (alternative form to classic for loop)
  for(int rolledVal : rolledValues){
     // check if rolled value equals given value
     if(rolledVal == value){
        // count it
        total++;
     }
  }

return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to a hashmap to make your search simpler

```
    private HashMap<Integer,Integer> rolledValues = new HashMap<>();
private int index = 0;

public void rollAndStore(int roll1){

    if (roll1 > index){
        //Do Nothing
        ;

    } else if (roll1 >= 0){ 
       index += 1;
       int rolledDie = die.roll();
       int amount = rolledValues.get(rolledDie);
       rolledValues.replace(rolledDie,amount+1);
    }

}


private int howMany(int die){
   return rolledValues.get(die);
}
```